# Ordenar Array multidimensiional java script

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de ordenar o mesmo para

```
id - 15135
id - 50
id - 25
```

Eu tentei usar

```
 array.sort
```

mas não funcionou.

Comment: Podes colocar o texto da consola aqui, como texto e não imagem, ? assim facilita a vida de quem quer ajudar com um exemplo.

Comment: `sort` é um método logo teria que ser `array.sort()` mas sem ver como está o código é difícil de ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var meuArray = [['4togm90gjwegn', 50], ['ef84itjdpodsdf4jg', 25], ['32r8uoijgtsdfsht', 15135]];

//Para ordenar em ordem crescente
meuArray.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
//Para ordenar em ordem decrescente
meuArray.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
```

O método sort, se chamado sem nenhum parâmetro tenta ordenar seu array comparando valores de strings, porém quando seu array não é constituído de strings, você pode passar uma função de callback com instruções para a organização.

Essa função recebe 2 argumentos, o primeiro e o próximo item do array (a e b), então cabe a você retornar um número maior que 0 para dizer que o elemento a precede b, ou menor que 0 para dizer que b precede a. Como os valores comparados são numéricos, nesse caso você pode apenas subtraí-los.